# Quote Bubble with Triangle at Bottom

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble figuring out how to make a CSS quote bubble with the triangle at the bottom left. I've found tons of CSS for speech bubbles, but either they do not expand with the text or the triangle is not on the bottom left (where I need it).

I've found a speech bubble that I really like, but it's triangle is on the left side because it was coded for a chat. If someone could explain to me how to adjust this code to make the bubble got to the bottom left, it would be greatly appreciated!

```
.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;    
}

.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content: "\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11px;
    transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
        -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    width:  20px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
    left: -9px; 
}
```

Here it is working in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/24S5L/2/

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Getting arrows at bottom is pretty easy, just use `bottom` instead of `top` and just some tweaks in `rotate` and `skew`

**CSS**

```
.chat {
    width: 400px;
}
.bubble {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
.bubble::before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    content:"\00a0";
    display: block;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7.5px;
    transform: rotate(47deg) skew(5deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(47deg) skew(5deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(47deg) skew(5deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(47deg) skew(5deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(47deg) skew(5deg);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, .4);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/V3Bnn/1/)

You can remove `div.chat` from HTML and CSS. There's no need for it.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for taking the time!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the bottom of the left or the left of the bottom?

If you mean the bottom of the left then simply replace:

```
top: 11px;
```

with

```
bottom: 11px;
```

like so...

```
.bubble::before {
background-color: #F2F2F2;
content: "\00a0";
display: block;
height: 16px;
position: absolute;
bottom: 11px;
transform:             rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -moz-transform:    rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -ms-transform:     rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -o-transform:      rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
    -webkit-transform: rotate( 29deg ) skew( -35deg );
width:  20px;
box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba( 178, 178, 178, .4 );
left: -9px; 
}
```

If not let me know and i'll have ago at positioning it on the bottom.
Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Thank you! I actually meant the left of the bottom though. I can't figure out how to get the arrow down there without specifying a height - which will cause errors depending on the size of the quote that goes into the bubble.

Answer (score 0):

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/24S5L/3/) - Is this what you wanted?

```
.bubble{
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #B2B2B2;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;   
    margin: 5px 45px 5px 20px;    
}


.bubble:before {
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    bottom: -5px;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(178, 178, 178, 0.4);
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    height: 13px;
    left: 11px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-68deg) skew(-35deg);
    width: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Almost! It's just the arrow isn't quite right (it's not flesh against the bottom like it was on the side)... Hmm... I'm sure it's just a matter of changing the skew and rotate properties but I'm changing them and it doesn't seem to be changing anything...

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick. Here's a fork of [THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/GZFK7/) too.

```
.bubble{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;

    float: left;
    clear: left; /* don't think you'll need this... it's going to be absolute eventually I bet */

    background-color: white;
    padding: 1em;

    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3); /* adjust howevers */
    border-radius: .2em;

    /* for placement only */
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}


.bubble:before {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background-color: white;

    height: 14px; /* you can do fancier stuff, but then the tringle digs into the box further... */
    width: 14px;
    bottom: -7px; /* < or = to half the fake triangle's width? */
    left: 15px;

    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.3); /* adjust howevers */

    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Comment: Basically the way the box model works is that relative = parent and absolute = child... sort of... for this explanation. The little box is positioned absolutely based on the shape of the parent(the closest surrounding element with position relative). So you just change it's position. The skew and rotation just make the little square a slightly different shape and turn it. So what is really needed is to say: left: 15px(or so); and bottom: -7px(or about half the width of the little square); Just little tweaks. For responsive reasons, it's best to keep things in ems (relative units) instead of px

Comment: haha - you guys actually explained it *and* you answered it first - with no love -  ha!

Answer (score 0):

- Simple Floating CSS Quote Box with Rounded Corners, Triangle Tip, and Box Shadow :

I ran into this similar problem and after much frustration, this is where I ended up.

**See the fiddle** here: http://jsfiddle.net/erikthedeveloper/CASJY/

Essentially, I have a .quote-box div that houses a p and two div's (.q-tip and .q-blocker).

I rotate the "tip" to create a triangle. Position it exactly center on the bottom of the quote box and "block" the top half of the tip with my .blocker div.   This leaves a nice shadow all around the quote box and the tip.

HTML

```
    <div class="quote-box">
        <p>
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, deleniti fugit quo tempora cupiditate in! Esse, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit, deleniti fugit quo tempora cupiditate in! Esse, excepturi..."
        </p>
        <!--[if gte IE 10]> -->
        <div class='q-tip q-rotate q-shadow'></div>
        <div class="q-blocker"></div>
        <!-- <![endif]-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.quote-box{
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.quote-box p{
    width: 90%;
    margin: 1.5em auto;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 1.75em;
    color: #636363;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.quote-box-tip{
    font-size: 2em;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    width: 0;
    left:45%;
    bottom:.5em;
}

.q-shadow, .quote-box{
    -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 0 #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 0 #000;
    box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 0 #000;
}
.q-tip{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-10px;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    z-index:1;
}
.q-blocker{
    width:80%;
    height:20px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:2;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
.q-rotate{
    /* Not working in IE8 and lower */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=0.5);
}
```

I hope that helps!